# while installing pecl extension in mongodb on ubuntu 16.04 i am getting this error

Tags: mongodb, php7

- List item

  when i am installing pecl i got this error.

  Makefile:194: recipe for target 'php_mongo.lo' failed
  make: *** [php_mongo.lo] Error 1
  ERROR: `make' failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pecl mongo extension is no longer maintained and new projects are advised to use the mongodb extension and PHP library.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php7.0-dev # required in order to use pecl 
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

The latest version of mongodb requires alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter in order to install mongodb packages with composer.

Comment: Thank you for replaying.after running these commands i got this "You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini".how can i add this extension.i totally new to that.

Comment: And thanks for helping the first issue has been resolved.i was stuck at that  point about 4 hours and finally i got the solution from you. @karel